# Debian 7.8 and samba libwbclient0 conflic

Tags: apt

I recently ran `dist-upgrade` on a server that did not see any updates for the past year. Now samba has stopped working. I have no idea what happened but it looks like samba somehow was uninstalled (can't find it using `locate samba`).

When I try `apt-get install samba` I get this response:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:3.6.6-6+deb7u5) but 2:4.1.17+dfsg-1~bpo70+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Trying to uninstall `libwbclient0` says this:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome gnome-control-center gnome-core gvfs-backends libgnomevfs2-extra libsmbclient libwbclient0 python-samba python-smbc samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules task-gnome-desktop
```

Which I obviously would like to avoid.

Are there any other ways to come around this problem? Running `aptitude` I end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `libwbclient0` was installed from [backports](http://backports.debian.org/), you need to re-install `samba` using

```
apt-get -t wheezy-backports install samba
```

(for the Debian 7 backports).